# How to suppress rescaling when doing imread on single channel png with cmap in python?

Tags: python, opencv, scipy

I need to load single channel png files that are stored along with a colormap in python. They contain indices of labels, so rescaling them is inappropriate for me.

I just noticed that for some strange reason both `scipy.misc.imread` and `cv2.imread` do rescale the images when loading them. How can I suppress that?

**Edit**:
I just tried the same on another single channel png without any colormap. It does not have the problem of rescaling. So the colormap seems to be the problem.

Here is an example image (it's single channel, colors come from the colormap):
[image: Here is an example image]

Comment: So how did you use these, e.g. which mode was selected using scipy's imread?

Comment: I tried `im = scipy.misc.imread(im_name, flatten = True)`. But as I stated above the fact that these png have color maps stored along with them seems to cause the problem. (In Matlab however it works)

Comment: Can you post one of the images somewhere?

Comment: If you save the file right back with `scipy.misc.imwrite()` you will see if the rescaling issue is really happening. The documentation says nothing above the behaviour you are observing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `scipy.misc.imread` (which is just a [deprecated] front-end to Pillow), use Pillow directly.  When an indexed `Image` object is given to `np.array()`, an array of the indices is created.

```
In [101]: from PIL import Image

In [102]: img = Image.open('WWpd3.png')

In [103]: a = np.array(img)

In [104]: a.shape, a.dtype
Out[104]: ((160, 320), dtype('uint8'))

In [105]: a.min(), a.max()
Out[105]: (0, 19)

In [106]: a[:3, :8]
Out[106]: 
array([[19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19],
       [19, 10, 10,  5,  5, 10, 10, 10],
       [19, 10, 10,  5,  5, 10, 10, 10]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! This was completely non obvious! In wonder why the question got 4 closing requests and a downvote...